# Check if an image exists

Tags: php, image

I have foreach loop that looks like this:

```
foreach($wdata->query->pages->$wpageid->images as $iimages)
{
$name = $iimages->title;
$filename = str_replace(" ", "_",$name);
$filename = str_replace("File:","",$filename);
$digest = md5($filename);
$folder = $digest[0].'/'.$digest[0].$digest[1].'/'. $filename;
$url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/'.$folder;
echo "<img style='height:100px;' src='$url'>";
}
```

It displayes images from a returned json array ($wdata)
However, some images have been moved, or don't exist anymore, and I get cracked images, does anyone know how to check if an image is real, exists and can be viewed before it is echoed

Comment: You might as-well use web crawlers to save the images so you can reference to them locally.

Comment: I hope for you that this loop is not running as part of an HTTP request from a user. It can kill performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `file_get_cotents()` function to check if it's there

```
if (file_get_contents("http://....") !== false) { //display image }
```

Comment: its on a url to another server, I have read that file_exists doesn't work for urls

Comment: its a uRL not a local path

Comment: then use `file_get_contents()` to get the image string then check if it's empty or not

Comment: you answer is still wrong, file_get_contents created an E_WARNNING on a 404 page, the return value is not set to false;

Comment: @Connor, use this example.  But insert an `@` before, file_get_contents. `@file_get_contents`. This will omit any E_WARNING's. Also, it is more reliable than DevZero0's answer below.

Comment: it doesn't matter if you suppress the warnings you still don't get false on a 404 page period.

Comment: Yes, it does. Do var_dump() on a file_get_contents function, with a broken URL specified.

Comment: Please see, http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php for more information.

Comment: so out of these examples, which should work, i tried them all, but got nothing... is there something i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is a remote file and `file_exists()` does not work for this circumstance. So I suggest you to use `getimagesize()` function which returns an array if the image exists.

```
<?php 

   $imageSize=getimagesize($url);

   if(!is_array($imageSize))
   {
       echo "<img style='height:100px;' src='$url'>";

   }
   else
   {
      echo "no image"; 
   }
?>
```

**Another solution:**

```
if (true === file_get_contents($url,0,null,0,1)) 
{
    echo  "<img style='height:100px;' src='$url'>";
}
```

This is faster because it tries to read only one byte of the file if exists.

Comment: first one cancels out a whole load of images except the one that is broken, second returns white space

Answer (score -1):

Use a function as below and pass your url for test

```
if (image_exist($url)) {
     echo "<img ...";
}

function image_exist($url) {
$file_headers = @get_headers($url);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 Found') {
     return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: you are only checking if the image was not found, what if it has been moved, there's a client error or server error?

Comment: your method will show content if there is error because there will be output

Comment: if you check my answer carefully you can see I'm not checking for content or output...

Comment: file_get_contents created an E_WARNNING on a 404 page, the return value is not set to false;